# Get data from drop menu rather than text input using flask

Tags: python, flask

How would i change this to drop boxes instead??I have this code which gets the user input entered in a text box and returns it to python.

Python code

```
@app.route('/signup', methods = ['POST'])
def signup():
    make = request.form['make']
    model=request.form['model']
    print("MAKE" +"= "+ make + "Model"+ "= "+ model)
    return redirect('/')
```

HTML FILE:

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="make"></input>
  <input type="text" name="model"></input>

  <input type="submit" value="Sumbit"></input>
</form>
```

What i mean by drop box:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

What ive got so far:

new html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</html>
```

new code:

```
@app.route('/signup', methods = ['POST'])
def signup():
    make = request.form['cars']
    print(make)
    return redirect('/')
```

Comment: what is a "drop box"— Are you asking how do you create a `select` html element with various options from which the user can choose?

Comment: yeah exactly, updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form elements require names— your example of a `select` field:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Needs to be more like:

```
<select name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Now your view can call the chosen result by calling `request.form["cars"]`

Comment: Hi, Ive posted the code that im now trying above. Python still doesnt print what i select in the drop box

Comment: You haven't created a form. Form elements need to live within a form.

Comment: <form action="/signup" method="post"></form> is that all i need to add?

Comment: Yes, if the form elements live within the form definition, it'll work. I'd recommend doing a basic introduction to html tutorial (W3C Schools is a simple starting point) to learn the basic constructs.