# Flask POST sign up form retrieve value of dropdown box

Tags: python, flask

I am using this HTML script for a sign up form in flask and the code will not let me retrieve the data in the same way I retrieve the username and password using `request.form['']`. I would like to pass the value of the option a user selects from a dropdown to my python program. Is there any way to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for any responses!

```
<select id="cell" name="carrier" data-name="cellcarrier">
                    <option value="verizon">Verizon</option>
                    <option value="att">At&amp;t</option>
                    <option value="tmobile">T-Mobile</option>
                    <option value="sprint">Sprint</option>
                    <option value="alltel">AllTel</option>
                    <option value="boost">Boost Mobile</option>
                    <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
                    <option value="metropcs">MetroPCS</option>
                    <option value="uscellular">US Cellular</option>
                    <option value="virginmobile">Virgin Mobile</option>
                    <option value="republicwireless">Republic Wireless</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Dropdown form boxes aren't special; you should be able to get the value of `carrier` the same way you would get any other form field.  Show us the code.

Comment: You should be able to get the value just by doing `request.form['carrier']`... https://stackoverflow.com/q/36208283/3990714

Comment: I resolved the issue thank you